# How to navigate to the last actionable element on a web page using keyboard shortcuts (for MAC)

Tags: accessibility, keyboard-shortcuts

For my web page I'm checking for **Accessibility** issues. I'm specifically checking for **Tab Order**.

By using <kbd>tab</kbd> I'm able to navigate to all the actionable elements(like links, dropdowns) of my page.

Now my issue is I have lot of these actionable elements. I want to reach the last one. Instead of pressing <kbd>tab</kbd> multiple times, is there a keyboard shortcut to directly navigate to it?

Comment: Might want to throw this up on superuser.com as it is more about how to use a screen reader rather than a programming problem. When you ask over there be sure to say which screen reader you are using (I am guessing VoiceOver but just to be sure). Try here -> https://dequeuniversity.com/screenreaders/voiceover-keyboard-shortcuts for the basics. I would probably do `VO` + `End` and then `shift` + `tab` to get to the last focusable item.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is not related to Screen reader/VoiceOver. This is for people who are not vision impaired and are keyboard focussed. They primarily would be using tabs.

For VoiceOver I'm able to navigate to the last element using VO + Fn + Right Arrow.

Comment: Ahh - I see, How about Command+ L to focus the URL bar and then shift + tab then?

Comment: Yes, that's the hack that I'm doing right now. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't know one, as I said superuser.com is a much better place to ask this so try over there as I am sure if there is a shortcut that someone will know it there.

Comment: Thanks Graham! :)

Comment: Another issue with that approach is if I have multiple tabs open on my browser... Shift + Tab will go through all the browser tabs before coming back to the last element of the page that i want to access. That's a bad user experience too.